# I need to do a lookup in Excel from another table and populate the row based on another column header

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have 2 workbooks. in WorkbookA , I'm doing the following query in column C - I need to look up the value in Column A on this row (row 7). I get that value, and perform a lookup on annual_leave, page called "percentage calc".  I look it up on Column B. If I find the value, I look for the column name and match. For example, my columns are months. So I make sure to populate the value in workbookA with the value in workbookB where the column in workbookB (row3) equals C1. For example, I look for where the colunn says "October, and update with the value for october)
[image: Column C under A/L is where im doing the query]

[image: Then here, is the table in the workbook called annual leave, with worksheet called percentage calc]

I've been trying a lookup and match but getting no luck, here's the code I've tried

```
=INDEX('[annual_leave].xlsx]percentage calc'!$C$4:$Z$1000, MATCH(A7, '[annual_leave]percentage calc'!$B$4:$B$1000, 0), MATCH(C1, '[WorkbookB.xlsx]percentage calc'!$C$3:$Z$3, 0))
```

(Both files are in the same folder)

Any ideas?

Overall, I need to populate October,November,Dec etc's A/L for each person but I want to look up the persons name in the other workbook and populate it automatically, so i dont need to change it when people leave and join.

Edit: I've changed the column names so they match  - IE October % =October %

[image: See additional image of column names]

Comment: Can you share the screenshots from both Sheets/Workbooks having the column and row names visible?

Comment: i added the screenshot for you

Comment: The present formula you are using will not work, because you have either used merged cells or center across selection, thus the lookup value always seats on the first cell therein you need a different formula to achieve your desired output, which is certainly possible. Also may i know the excel version you are using?